# Recarregar após atualização

Tags: php, jquery, json

Estou fazendo uma alteração de status em meu banco de dados usando `$.getJSON`, está dando certo, mas no retorno preciso atualizar a `div` onde estão os dados e não estou conseguindo realizar essa tarefa, vejam o código abaixo:

```js
<script>
$(function(){       
    $("[name='btncapa']").on('click',function(e){

        var IdProduto   = $(this).attr('IdProduto');
        var IdProdutoFoto = $(this).attr('IdProdutoFoto');
        var $el = $(this);

        bootbox.dialog({
            message: "Confirma a marcação de capa?",
            title: "Capa",
            buttons: {
                success: {
                    label: "Sim",
                    className: "btn-success",
                    callback: function() {
                        $.getJSON('MarcaItemFoto.php', {IdProduto: IdProduto, IdProdutoFoto: IdProdutoFoto},  function(resposta){
                            $("#diverro").html("<div class='alert alert-error'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button><strong>ERRO!</strong> " + resposta.erro + "</div>");
                        });
                        $el.parents('li').load();
                    }
                },
                danger: {
                    label: "Não",
                    className: "btn-danger",
                    callback: function() {
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `.load(URL)` tem um parâmetro obrigatório, uma URL que irá retornar essa lista `li`, `$.getJSON(URL, json, functionSucess)` pelo que entendi, vc quer carregar a lista `li` depois de fazer o 'MarcaItemFoto.php'? 'MarcaItemFoto.php' retorna o que?

Comment: Olá bigown, boa noite, ele me retorna o status da operação, sendo true/false ai trato a mensagem se for um erro, senão gostaria de atualizar a lista.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Há dois problemas em potencial com o seu código:

1. Você parece estar tratando somente de condições de erro no *callback* (função anônima que você passa como parâmetro pro `getJSON`), mas não condições de sucesso. Além disso, como mencionado por @marcusagm, essa função só será chamada se **a requisição** tiver sucesso, ainda que **a lógica do seu programa** não tenha. Se houver um problema com a requisição em si (ex.: *timeout*, 404 não encontrado, 500 erro interno no servidor, etc) nenhum código será chamado.

   Para corrigir isso, sugiro passar também um *callback* para erros. Se estiver usando uma versão recente do jQuery, o ideal seria:

   ```
   $.getJSON(url, parametros)
       .done(function(resposta) { /* sucesso */ })
       .fail(function() { /* erro */ });
   ```

   Se quiser mesmo uma única função pra tratar erro ou sucesso, pode usar o `then`:

   ```
   $.getJSON(url, parametros).then(function(resposta) { 
       /* sucesso ou erro */ 
   });
   ```
2. As requisições Ajax, como o próprio nome diz, são **assíncronas**. A chamada de `getJSON` retorna antes mesmo dela ter sido realizada (e completada). Por isso, qualquer código que você coloque depois dela irá executar **antes** do Ajax ser feito, não **depois**.

   Qualquer coisa que você queira executar só depois da resposta estar pronta, você deve colocar no *callback* da requisição. Exemplo:

   ```
   $.getJSON(url, parametros).done(function(resposta) { 
       $el.parents('li').load();
   });
   ```

   (Não sei se era esse seu objetivo com essa linha de código, mas suspeito que seja: recarregar só depois do Ajax estar pronto)

P.S. Na pergunta você também diz que está fazendo uma "alteração de status", certo? Nesse caso, a melhor prática seria não utilizar um `HTTP GET` para isso, mas sim um `POST`. Exemplo:

```
$.post(url, parametros, "json").done(function(resposta) { 
    $el.parents('li').load();
});
```

Comment: Lembrando que a função load não carrega os dados diretamente. É necessário de tratar a atualização para cada parte, seja retornando a lista em html no retorno da requisição e atualizar usando a função html(). Ou retornar um JSON e tratar logo em seguida adicionando o html

Answer (score 2):

Voçê está fazendo a requisição e em caso de sucesso tratou apenas para erro.

```
$.getJSON('MarcaItemFoto.php', {IdProduto: IdProduto, IdProdutoFoto: IdProdutoFoto},  function(resposta){
  // Aqui você deve tratar se realmente ocorreu um erro ou não.
  // Esta funcão é utilizada caso a requisição retorne um status de sucesso.
  // Aqui você tambem deve tratar os casos de sucesso, como atualizar a lista de que precisa.
});
```

O Load faz outra requisição Ajax veja os parametros na [documentação](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$el.parents('li').load('caminho/para/retornar/o/html/atualizado');
```

Recomendo tratar tambem quando a requisição retornar um código de erro não esperado usando a função fail() do jquery. Ficaria assim:

```
$.getJSON('MarcaItemFoto.php', {IdProduto: IdProduto, IdProdutoFoto: IdProdutoFoto},  function(resposta){
   // Ação após obter resultado com código de sucesso
}).fail(
  function () {
    // Ação após obter resultado com código de erro
  }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

A solução para o meu problema, foi isso:

```
$.post(url, parametros, "json").done(function(resposta) { 
    $el.parents('li').load();
});
```

Dica dada pelo mgibsonbr.
Obrigado.